# Cannot Remove Selected D3 SVG Elements with .exit() .remove() api

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am visualizing audio frequency data as rectangular waveforms and circle widths. The audio data is passed as an audio node through the Web Audio API. The elements appear on screen, however I cannot remove them with the .exit().remove() D3 pattern. This causes significant lag on the application. Here is how the code looks that creates each unique svg:

```
const circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(frequencyData);

  circles.exit().remove();
  circles.enter().append('circle')
    .merge(circles)
    .attr('cx', svgWidth / 2)
    .attr('cy', svgHeight / 2)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
    .attr('r', d => rangeScale(d))
    .attr('stroke', d => d3.hsl(hslScale(d), 1, 0.85));


const rects = svgMonitor.selectAll('rect')
    .data(frequencyData);
  rects.remove();
  rects.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', d => 150 - Math.random() * d)
    .attr('y', d => -waveLength(d))
    .attr('width', d => rangeScale(d))
    .attr('height', 3)
    .attr('fill', d => d3.hsl(hslScale(d), 1, 0.85))
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(90)');

  rects.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', d => 150 - Math.random() * (max - d))
    .attr('y', d => -waveLength2(d))
    .attr('width', d => rangeScale(max - d))
    .attr('height', 3)
    .attr('fill', d => d3.hsl(hslScale(d), 1, 0.85))
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(90)');
```

This pattern does not cause the elements be to removed from screen. However, If I write:

```
  circles.enter().append('circle')
    .merge(circles)
    .attr('cx', svgWidth / 2)
    .attr('cy', svgHeight / 2)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
    .attr('r', d => rangeScale(d))
    .attr('stroke', d => d3.hsl(hslScale(d), 1, 0.85))
    .remove();
```

The elements are removed, however they do not stay long enough on screen to even be visible. I understand that D3 should follow the enter(), update(), exit() pattern, and this is how I structured my above code. Should this be written somehow differently? Thank you.

Comment: Circles code looks good. Have you verified `frequencyData` is correct?

Comment: Your rects code looks very odd though. Why do you remove all constantly? Why do you have enter().append() twice?

Comment: If you need two pieces of rect for each entry of data, group them into a `g`

Comment: Frequency data is correct. The two pieces of rects are used to make a waveform reflected on the y-axis. On the left side of the display if goes from small to big and on the right from big to small

Comment: Without seeing more (preferable a complete but minimal example in fiddle), it's hard to say anything else

Comment: I have local audio files that I use, so it would take a while to replicate in fiddle. Is there any other piece of code that I could provide instead? For example, how I am calling these functions or how it's being looped, etc?